# Matching items in one table that don't match in a subset of a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a Product table, and a

```
id product
1  Apple
2  Bag
3  Cat
4  Ducati
```

and a Cart table

```
 id  user_id   product_id
 1     1          2
 2     1          3
 3     2          1
 4     3          1
```

So, I want to look at a particular user and see what he/she does NOT have in their Cart.

In other words, in the above example

```
SELECT ...... WHERE user_id=1 .....
```

would return Apple and Ducati because User 1 already has Bag and Cat.

(This may well duplicate another question but there are so many variations I couldn't find the exact match and put in these simple terms may help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a left join from product to all products purchased by user1, which can be retrieved with a subselect in the join. This will cause all product id's that are not in user1's care to have null product ids.  The where clause will select all null product id's meaning they will not have been in a users cart, essentially filtering purchased items.

```
select p.name
from product p
left join (select product_id, user_id
           from cart where user_id = 1)
c
on p.id = c.product_id
where c.product_id is null;
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5318eb/17

Comment: It's good practice to add some details in your answer about your solution, not just the code.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Getting to that part.

Comment: @Gazzer try the last one

Comment: Looking good :-) Perhaps the explanation needs to be updated. (My product table has id rather than product_id).

Comment: Your a tough customer, j/k.  Code example should now match the defined problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  * 
From Product p
Where p.id Not In
    (
        Select c.product_id
        From Cart c
        Where User ID = ____
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product FROM product_table 
WHERE product NOT IN
(SELECT product_id FROM cart_table WHERE user_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all product for all users  which are not in there cart.

```
select  c.user_id,a.Product
from cart c Cross Join product a 
left Join 
cart b on b.product_id=a.id and c.user_id=b.user_Id
where b.product_id is null
group by  c.user_id,a.Product
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a84/16)